How to compare each letter in a string to a pointer that holds letters in an array
I am creating a game that is essentially word-hunt on iMessage. (Has a grid of letters and make words by drawing a line through them).
In my current work, I am searching through a standard dictionary to find possible words. I can pretty much figure out how to do that on a 2d array if I knew how to compare the letter of a word to a pointer of an array of letters. My letters are held in wordhunt, a struct that takes the data of an input file:
    3 3                                number of rows & columns in the strand grid
    3                                the length of the words to find
    t l e a u n i s h         the letters that populate the strand grid

Here is the struct:
typedef struct wordhunt
{
    char** words;
    char** letters;
    int rows, cols;
    int numWords;
    int wordLen;
} wordhunt_t;

for now, to access these letters I use wordhunt->letters[j], but comparing this with each letter in a word[i] doesn't work due to type difference. How could I fix this?
I assume somehow storing this on a new array outside the struct would make it work, and I can do that with the integers from the input file, but I can't figure out how that translates to words and characters etc.
//assume word is pulled from the dictionary correctly, iterating through each letter in a loop as well
if (word[i] == wordhunt->letters[j]){

     //tracks that each letter in the word is within the array of letters, used later
     ++validLetterCt
     
     //break out of loop to look at next letter in word
     break;
}


You have char** letters;, i.e. letters is a pointer to pointer to char. Consequently letter[j] will be a pointer to char. And letters[j][i] will be a char. I guess that's what you are looking for.

This code iterates through each cell in the grid, comparing each letter of the word with the letters in the grid, and increments validLetterCt when a match is found.
for (int j = 0; j < wordhunt->rows; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < wordhunt->cols; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < wordLen; i++) {
            if (word[i] == wordhunt->letters[j][k]) {
                ++validLetterCt;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

